# configure utf8 in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

i do copy data from one db to another. first DB has cp1251 codepage.

step one

i did copy data from first db to simple csv file using simple java programm. Console out is readable during extracting data from DB.

codepage of csv file utf-8 (i checked it in several text editor and all data is readable, and text editor define charset of file as utf-8)

java machine default charset is utf-8
csv file in utf8 charset
new mysql db is in utf8 file

this out on command status in mysql cmd

```
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp866
Conn.  characterset:    cp866
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 25 min 29 sec
```

all tables and charsets in mysql db are in utf-8

i insert data into mysql using another simple java programm

data in mysql is unreadble

config for mysql server

```
[server]

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
character_sets-dir="C:/Programm/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

fount on server side that jvm using utf16 not a utf8 which could be issue with preparedstatement in jdbc.

Comment: Show the code for how you connect to the database and example how you send queries.

Answer (score 0):

The java connection string for the JDBC communication:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

There is overlap/redundance/too-much in the settings (server + client + JDBC-communication),
but that should do it for the JDBC part.

If the problems persist, try again default settings, and specify UTF-8 on the CREATE DATABASE/TABLE/column.

Comment: i did tried it as well with no effect as well as "all tables and charsets in mysql db are in utf-8" db itself as well in utf-8

Comment: Do you any file operations in java?